# mount google drive in kaggle notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, kaggle

In google colab, I easily mount my google drive with this:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

In kaggle's notebook, however, it gives this error:

```py
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-2b128295b616> in <module>
      2 # !pip install google-colab
      3 from google.colab import drive
----> 4 drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
      5 # Set your own project id here
      6 # PROJECT_ID = 'your-google-cloud-project'

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/colab/drive.py in mount(mountpoint, force_remount, timeout_ms)
     80     return
     81 
---> 82   env = _env()
     83   home = env.home
     84   root_dir = env.root_dir

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/colab/drive.py in _env()
     41   home = _os.environ['HOME']
     42   root_dir = _os.path.realpath(
---> 43       _os.path.join(_os.environ['CLOUDSDK_CONFIG'], '../..'))
     44   inet_family = 'IPV4_ONLY'
     45   dev = '/dev/fuse'

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    667         except KeyError:
    668             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 669             raise KeyError(key) from None
    670         return self.decodevalue(value)
    671 

KeyError: 'CLOUDSDK_CONFIG'
```

This is my setup in kaggle notebook (also tested [this](https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/64001), did not work):

```py
!pip install google-colab # I don't know if this is the correct package
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Answer (score 12):

In fact, the `google-colab` library does not exist in the Kaggle Kernel. In this way, I use the following procedure to deal with this problem in Kaggle Kernel:

- First, extract the ID of your desire file from google drive:

  1. In your browser, navigate to drive.google.com.
  2. Right-click on the file, and click "Get a shareable link"

     [image: Right click get shareable link]
  3. Then extract the ID of file from URL:

     [image]
- Next, install `gdown` PyPI module using `conda`:

  `! conda install -y gdown`
- Finally, download the file using `gdown` and the intended ID:

  `!gdown --id <put-the-ID>`

For example:

`!gdown --id 1-1wAx7b-USG0eQwIBVwVDUl3K1_1ReCt`

Comment: is there a way to do the same with folders? i have tried this method with folders on google drive but it does not work I was wondering if there was another way ?

Comment: @vipulpetkar Are you mean is downloading a file that is into a subfolder or you want to download a folder directly?

Comment: I want to download an entire drive folder directly into kaggle. I have 10,000 images in google drive folder and i want to send them to kaggle, i dont have any other option than to send and entire folder.

Comment: @vipulpetkar An alternative way is to create a CloudFare workers (https://workers.cloudflare.com/) to access your files on Google Drive. I believe that would work. You need to dig a bit on Internet to find tutorial on how to do. I remember there is a tool that helps you configure but can't find it in my history

Answer (score 3):

`google-colab` is not maintained by Google, and Colab libraries like `drive.mount` won't work outside of the Colab environment itself.

Answer (score 0):

As the stack trace suggests you have some keys missing.

- CLOUDSDK_CONFIG

You can get this key by logging into GCP and searching for creds

To use these secretively: place this key into Kaggle Secrets Add-ons.

Comment: Another way to do this try logging the keys and activities from the drive mount script in Google Colab to get that keys