# mounting google drive folder on kaggle

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, kaggle

I have images stored in a google drive folder so that it can be trained using deep networks. How to **mount** the **folder** or entire drive in **kaggle**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mount google drive in kaggle notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715317/mount-google-drive-in-kaggle-notebook)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation and the only solution I have found was this stackoverflow thread:

[mount google drive in kaggle notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715317/mount-google-drive-in-kaggle-notebook)