# Do we still don't have any way to access folders from google drive on kaggle?

Tags: python, kaggle, google-drive-shared-drive

I have relatively huge dataset (apprx 5 GB) of images stored on google drive in a folder. I wanted to do some processing and apply deep learning algorithms on the dataset. For this to be possible, I must have dataset in the kaggle environment. I searched online, and realised that there is no way, or, at least this is what I have been able to gather yet.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63961257/15031437) makes use of gdown library, but probably google drive denies access because of cookies issues. I tried mounting my cookies to the kaggle environment. But this was of no use.

I might need to write some other scripts for downloading the data itself. May be first storing the links of individual files in the google drive folder and then traversing over the links in the kaggle environment would help. But I was lazy.

I wanted to know if there is some way this could be done?

Comment: Afaik your best option is still converting the data to a single (or few) compressed files with colab and then using gdown to have them on the Kaggle kernel.

Comment: @PaoloJ42 well earlier I tried this by first having the folder on my local machine, then uploaded the zipped folder to kaggle via upload. but this did not go good as well.

Comment: @PaoloJ42 yeah I finally got the solution. Yours worked. Probably I was doing it wrong way earlier. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I could not find a better way. But here is what worked for me, as @PaoloJ42 suggested me:

1. Download the dataset from the Google drive. (It will be in zipped form already)
2. Instead of uploading the zipped folder to Upload Data option in kaggle environment, it is better to create your own dataset in the Kaggle. Make use of Dataset > New Dataset. You can choose to make it private.
3. After it is uploaded, the zipped folder gets automatically unzipped. You can make use of the link. Just add the following snippet:

   ```
   import os
   os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = 'username'
   os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = 'kaggle_key'
   ```

You can get the above from Settings > Create New Token (under API section)

This way you don't have to upload every now and then.